# A problem in proving a identity with tensor notation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

There is an exercise that has me prove the following identity $J^i_{i'j'}J^{i'}_j+J^i_{i'}J^{i'}_{jk}J^k_{j'}=0$
from the identity $J^i_{i'j'}J^{i'}_jJ^{j'}_k+J^i_{i'}J^{i'}_{jk}=0$. The problem states that I have to contract the identity with $J^k_{k'}$ and then rename $j'\rightarrow k'$. Why is it allowed to change the names of the indices? I did it anyway and got $J^i_{i'j'}J^{i'}_j\delta^{k'}_{k'}+J^i_{i'}J^{i'}_{jk}J^k_{k'}=3J^i_{i'j'}J^{i'}_j+J^i_{i'}J^{i'}_{jk}J^k_{k'}=0$ and now I am stuck here.

Edit: By these $J_{i}^{j}$s I mean $i,j$ entries of the jacobian matrix.

Comment: Names of indices are not important when they are used in summations. $\sum_{i=0}^3a_i=\sum_{j=0}^3a_j$. So renaming is allowed. What is not allowed is inconsistent *arbitrary* renaming, such as $J_{ik}J^{kl}=J_{lj}J^{ji}$.

Comment: Can you give us more information of what are these $J_{i}^j$ objects? For example, how did you obtained that $J_{k}^{j'}J_{k'}^k = \delta_{k'}^{j'}$? Are there any other properties we can use?

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as someone said in the comments, indices names are sometimes just "dummy" indices. So when indices appear repeated such as here $A_iA^i$, this means $\sum_{i=1}^n A_iA^i = \sum_{j=1}^n A_jA^j$. So the result is the same no matter what name you use for the index. This is similar to what happens with dummy variables in integration: $\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^b f(u)du$. For a similar reason You can also change the name of indices which are not involved in a summation (not repeated), as long as change them in all the terms (both sides of the equation). For example, imagine I have the identity $a_i +c_i= b_i$, then it doesn't matter if I state it as $a_j +c_j= b_j$ (renaming $i$ as $j$ in all terms) but I cannot write $a_i +c_i= b_j$ or $a_i +c_j= b_j$. Using this rules you can change names while keeping consistency in the equations.

Now regarding to the identities. I don't know all the context but from what you wrote it seems that $J_{k}^{j'}J_{k'}^k = \delta_{k'}^{j'}$ right?. Then let me just remind you a classical trick with $\delta_{j}^k$. If you have $\delta_{j}^k$ multiplying with another symbol which share some index in a summation, then you can substitute indices as follows: for example $J_{i'j'}^i\delta_{k'}^{j'} = J_{i'k'}^i$, where $J_{i'j'}^i$ and $\delta_{k'}^{j'} $ share the repeated index $j'$, then $j'$ in $J_{i'j'}^i$ changes to the other index contained in $\delta_{k'}^{j'}$, resulting in $J_{i'k'}^i$ (and the Kronecker delta disappears). Why is that? Note that $\delta_{k'}^{j'}=0$ unless $k'=j'$, hence all terms in the summation $J_{i'j'}^i\delta_{k'}^{j'}$ disappear except for $J_{i'k'}^i$.

We are now ready to show the identity. First, contract with $J_{k'}^k$ just as you did:
$$
J_{i'j'}^iJ_{j}^{i'}J_k^{j'}J_{k'}^k + J_{i'}^iJ_{jk}^{i'}J_{k'}^k=0
$$
Now use the fact that $J_k^{j'}J_{k'}^k = \delta_{k'}^{j'}$:
$$
J_{i'j'}^iJ_{j}^{i'}\delta_{k'}^{j'} + J_{i'}^iJ_{jk}^{i'}J_{k'}^k=0
$$
Now, use the kronecker delta substitution trick to write $J_{i'j'}^i\delta_{k'}^{j'}  = J_{i'k'}^i$:
$$
J_{i'k'}^iJ_{j}^{i'}+ J_{i'}^iJ_{jk}^{i'}J_{k'}^k=0
$$
Note that $J_{j}^{i'}$ doesn't share any indices with $\delta_{k'}^{j'} $ so it remains the same. Now rename $k'$ as $j'$ in all the equation: change all occurrences of $k'$ to $j'$:
$$
J_{i'j'}^iJ_{j}^{i'}+ J_{i'}^iJ_{jk}^{i'}J_{j'}^k=0
$$
which finishes the proof.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear with my question. The J:s in the equation represent entries in the jacobian matrix. I'll add that to my question to make it more clear to anyone reading this afterwards. Thank you so much for showing that trick with kroneckers for it cleared up everything. I actually knew about it but somehow it didn't cross my mind this  time. Also it makes a lot of sense that you can rename repeated indicies as they are part of a sum.

Comment: No problem! Good luck!